# in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /models/task (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, factory-bot, rspec-rails

In my helper I want to specify models that I created in model folder but It can't pick up ones.
When I run rspec to test, I got this error:

```
/home/alex/dev/greenbull/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `require_relative':
cannot load such file -- /home/alex/dev/greenbull/models/task (LoadError)
```

Here's the **/spec** folder structure

```
|-models
| |_
|   |-task.rb
|   |-user.rb
|   |-task_spec.rb
|   |-user_spec.rb
|
|-factories
| |_
|   |-tasks.rb
|   |-users.rb
|
|-spec_helper.rb
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'factory_girl'

require_relative '../models/task'
require_relative '../models/user'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to write require_relative in spec_helper.rb.
Try removing these two lines

```
require_relative '../models/task'
require_relative '../models/user'
```

model will get included automatically

Answer (score 1):

You don't need require file in spec_helper because rails load automatically all file.